# Repeat use of array if maximum is reach

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to code in App Script a function that would assign a new color for a specific list (clients sheet column A only).

1st is the clientlist array depends on the clientsheet column A (row 2 until lastrow)
2nd is a bgcolor array that list a hexcolor of 1 to 3
3rd is a fncolor array that list a hexcolor of 1 to 3

What I need is to scan each clientlist and give a corresponding color from the bgcolor and fncolor, if the maximum bgcolor and fncolor is met but there are still values in clientlist, the array will go back to start and start over again. I have this existing code which I am lost on how would it give color but I think I am just missing something.

I hope anyone could solve my problem. Thanks.

```
function newAssignColor() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clientLists = ss.getSheetByName('Clients'); 

  var bgcolors = [['#000000'], ['#000033'], ['#000066']];
  var fncolors = [['#ffffff'], ['#ffffff'], ['#ffffff']];

  var r = clientLists.getRange(1, 1, clientLists.getLastRow(),1);
  var data = r.getValues();

  for (var i=1; i<=data.length; i++) {     
          if (i-1 <= bgcolors.length) {
            var j = i-1;
            i = j;
          }
          else { var j = 0; i =j;}

          if (data[i][0] !== "") {
          clientLists.getRange(i,1,1,1).setBackground(bgcolors[j][0]);
          clientLists.getRange(i,1,1,1).setFontColor(fncolors[j][0]);
  }} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we iterate the data array, we can then get the background color using the index and using the % operator, so once we exhaust the color array, we start from the first. again. Here is the code snippet.

```
function newAssignColor() {

  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clientLists = ss.getSheetByName('Clients'); 

  var bgcolors = ['#000000', '#000033', '#000066'];
  var fncolors = ['#ffffff', '#fffff0', '#fffff1'];

  var r = clientLists.getRange(1, 1, clientLists.getLastRow(),1);
  var data = r.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {   
    Logger.log("Data Value " + i + " : " + data[i]);
    var totalBgColors = bgcolors.length;
    var totalFgColors = fncolors.length;

    var bgColor = bgcolors[i%totalBgColors];
    var fgColor = fncolors[i%totalFgColors];
    Logger.log("BG Color: " + bgColor);
    Logger.log("FG Color: " + fgColor);

  } 
}
```

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: thanks that works! just need to fix a lil bit but it really helped.. thanks manish!

Answer (score 1):

Final Code here credits to manish given code:

Assigning new colors for each items in the list starting in row 2. when maximum color is reached, repeat to first color of the array.

```
function newAssignColor() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var clientLists = ss.getSheetByName('Clients'); 

  var bgcolors = [['#000000'], ['#000033'], ['#000066']];
  var fgColors = [['#ffffff'], ['#ffffff'], ['#ffffff']];

  var r = clientLists.getRange(1, 1, clientLists.getLastRow(),1);
  var data = r.getValues();

  for (var i=2; i<=data.length; i++) {     
    var totalBgColors = bgcolors.length;
    var totalFgColors = fgColors.length;

    var bgColor = bgcolors[i%totalBgColors];
    var fgColor = fgColors[i%totalFgColors];

          if (data[i] !== "") {
          clientLists.getRange(i,1,1,1).setBackground(bgColor);
          clientLists.getRange(i,1,1,1).setFontColor(fgColor);
  }} 
}
```